# Can I use an EAGLView in my UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, opengl-es, eaglview

I have a UIViewController that instantiates several UIImageViews on the screen. Is it possible to instantiate an EAGLView (like the one in the OpenGL ES template in the iPhone SDK) in a similar manner in my View Controller, and possibly have the UIImageViews as well as an EAGLView all running simultaneously on the same screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It would be possible. The problem is that Mixing UIKit stuff in some views, and the EAGLView Open GL ES calls, [can lead to serious performance issues](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2230.html#TNTAG4) (and fps drops). I would recommend to make a view controller for each view that you want to add to your superView.

For example for a game with a menu, I like doing a separate OpenGL ES views for each menu item, for lazy loading them, instead of making all in one OpenGL ES enabled view, I think the code is more easy to maintain that way.

I hope I understood your question correctly :-)

Comment: I'ts inappropriate to use only a single EAGLView ?, because inside my opengl code i make sure to load and draw resources to each of the scenes, and i unload them whenever i want to draw a different view.

Comment: It's not inappropriate at all if you manage them correctly!, I think that is a pretty good practice, you should checkout the game "Flowers".